# How to insert inactive [timestamp] via function?

Tags: org-mode, time-date, prefix-argument

<kbd>C-u C-c !</kbd>  generates a time stamp like [2015-05-04 Mon 17:13]

I would like to assign a shortcut (e.g F1) to this action.

So far I have:

```
(defun my/timenow (&optional arg) 
 (interactive) 
 (let ((current-prefix-arg 4)) ;; emulate C-u
 (org-time-stamp arg 'inactive)
 )
)
```

But this prompts me for the time and I have to press <kbd>RET</kbd> to insert it.

How can I insert the inactive timestamp without any prompts at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation of `org-time-stamp`:

> With two universal prefix arguments, insert an active timestamp
>   with the current time without prompting the user.

So eval the below:

```el
(org-time-stamp '(16) t)
```

- `'(4)` - one prefix arg (4)
- `'(16)` - two prefix args (4 * 4)
- `'(64)` - three prefix args (4 * 4 * 4)

To read more about the universal arguments and arguments in general:

- [Prefix Command Args - Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html)
- [Arguments - Elisp Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html)
- [Elisp Universal Args - ergoemacs.org](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_universal_argument.html)

Comment: Bonus points for explaining the 4/16/64 notion of prefix args ^_^. Thank you.

Comment: This command `(insert (org-time-stamp '(16) t))` inserts two timestamps next to each other. Do you know why?

Comment: @mmorin if you look at `org-time-stamp` code (use M-x find-function), it's inserting by itself, so you don't need extra `insert`. Alternatively, you can use `insert` with a combination of `format-time-string` and `org-time-stamp-format`.

Comment: One interesting thing I noticed is that `org-time-stamp` **requires** an argument to be called since it's `(defun org-time-stamp (arg &optional inactive) ...)`. I wonder what argument is actually passed in when you press `C-c .`. I was not able to simulate that programatically.

Comment: Can this solution be modified to insert the date part only, and not the time?

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a dedicated function for this (see `org-time-stamp-inactive`). For example:

```
(defun my/timenow ()
 (interactive)
 (let ((current-prefix-arg '(16)))
   (call-interactively 'org-time-stamp-inactive)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f1>") 'my/timenow)
```

You can also skip the prompt with two universal prefix
arguments: `C-u C-u C-c !`.