# Can an (insert)ed string be captured?

Tags: org-mode

In [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12130/how-to-insert-inactive-timestamp-via-function), the OP is asking how to insert an inactive `org-mode` timestamp which is (almost) what I want.  One of the responders (@xji) noted that the function `org-time-stamp-inactive` would *insert* the inactive timestamp.  What I'm trying to do is to use an inactive timestamp in a property like this:

```el
(defun add-property-with-date-captured ()
  "Add DATE_CAPTURED property to the current item."
  (interactive)
  (org-set-property "CREATED" (org-time-stamp-inactive))
)
```

However, that function is interactive, I just want it to insert the current date/time.  I tried passing with two universal prefix arguments:

```el
(org-set-property "CREATED" (org-time-stamp-inactive '(16)))
```

It's not interactive but it inserts it twice.

In response to that, to "capture" the results of the function I tried using the approach suggested by @erikstokes in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13208/yasnippet-invoked-org-time-stamp-function-inserts-double-timestamp):

```el
(defun add-property-with-date-captured ()
  "Add DATE_CAPTURED property to the current item."
  (interactive)
  (let ((inactivets (org-insert-time-stamp nil t t ))
    (org-set-property "CREATED" inactivets)
  )
)
```

but I still get an extra entry as described the OP of that question.

Currently I am using this as @kgo suggested in the same question:

```el
(defun add-property-with-date-captured ()
  "Add DATE_CAPTURED property to the current item."
  (interactive)
  (org-set-property "CREATED" (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M]"))
)
```

It works fine but now I'm just wondering why the method described by @erikstokes didn't work for me.

Can someone suggest how I can do this using the built-in `org-time-stamp-inactive` function?

Comment: In your case, you don't want to insert a time stamp at all: you jut want to capture it for future use. @erikstokes's method discards the return value so that the timestamp is not inserted twice - but it does not do anything about the timestamp that the function itself inserts. So you cannot use that method for your purposes. But the temp-buffer solution in the answer below is a *general* solution to that problem - perfect for your purposes.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Exactly, what you want is the opposite of what my answer does. I discard the return value to keep only the insertion. You need to discard the insertion and keep the return value, which the `with-temp-buffer` solution does.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it makes sense now!  That's a pretty cool function, it will be handy.  Sorry about the mis-tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Any time a function inserts text into the current buffer when you want it as a string, you can use the `with-temp-buffer` macro:

```
(defun add-property-with-date-captured ()
  "Add DATE_CAPTURED property to the current item."
  (interactive)
  (org-set-property "CREATED"
                    (with-temp-buffer
                      (org-time-stamp-inactive)
                      (buffer-string))))
```

This macro creates a new temporary buffer, sets it as the current buffer, then evaluates the code you gave it: in your case, that inserts the timestamp in the temp buffer and it then captures and returns the contents of the buffer as a string. For more details, see the doc strings of the relevant functions: `C-h f with-temp-buffer RET` and `C-h f buffer-string RET`.